# python where function doesn't work

Tags: python, numpy

I'm dealing with a longitude array named `LON`, but I encountered some problems with the `numpy.where()` function.

```
>>> print LON[777,777]
13.4635573678
>>> print np.where(LON == 13.4635573678)[0]
[]
>>> print np.where(LON == 13.4635573678)[1]
[]
```

It doesn't find the `LON` entry where the array is equal to a value that certainly exists. Is the problem related to the fact I'm dealing with double variables? Because until now `np.where()` always worked fine for both integers, floats and strings...

Comment: 13.4635573678 is not in your array. The print statement does not display all digits. Try `np.where(LON == LON[777, 777])[0]`.

Comment: Yes, it gives me back the right answer... but it's kind of a dog biting its tail :) How do I get all digits of my LON[777,777] entry?

Comment: Why would you *want* all digits?

Comment: You could try `np.where(abs(LON - 13.4635573678) < 0.01)` or something like that.

Comment: In order to get the entry. I mean, I have a longitude value (e.g., 13.46): I wrote a function for retrieving the nearest value to 13.4 within the LON array and this is 13.4635573678. Now I need to find the position of this value inside my array, i.e. [777,777].

Comment: Why don't you rewrite that function to return you both the value and its index?

Comment: @tobias_k this could be a nice idea, thanks!

Comment: @tobias_k because mostly I don't know how to get the index related to a certain value without using the where function...

Comment: `float` comparison is always tricky... i see that you are using python 2. starting from python 3.5 you can use [math.isclose](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#pep-485-a-function-for-testing-approximate-equality) to compare `float`s.

Comment: thanks for the tip @hiroprotagonist, but unfortunately I need to use version 2.7 for other reasons...

Answer (score 3):

One way to work around this might be to use `np.where` with an approximate match:

```
>>> X = np.linspace(1, 10, 100).reshape((10,10))
>>> np.where(abs(X - 6.3) < 0.1)
(array([5, 5]), array([8, 9]))
>>> X[np.where(abs(X - 6.3) < 0.1)]
array([ 6.27272727,  6.36363636])
```

Of course, this could give you more than one match, if the epsilon (0.1 in this example) is too large, but the same could be the case when using an exact match, in case there are multiple entries in the array with the same coordinate.

Edit: as pointed out [in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35605501/python-where-function-doesnt-work/35606162#comment58905274_35606162), you could also use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html), even with Python 2.7 where `math.isclose` is not available. Note, however, that `np.isclose` will not give an array of coordinates, but an array of `True`/`False`. If you need the coordinates, you could pipe the result of `np.close` through `np.where` again.

```
>>> np.where(np.isclose(X, 6.3636))
(array([5]), array([9]))
>>> X[np.isclose(X, 6.3636)]
array([ 6.36363636])
```

Alternatively, you could consider changing the function that gave you that coordinate from the `LON` array to also return the position of that value *in* the array. This way, you would not need to use `np.where` at all.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can use `np.isclose` instead. For example: `X[np.isclose(X, 6.3)]`

Comment: @JoeKington Thanks, did not know this function. Added it to the answer.